# Working on Project Tango OS

Tags: google-project-tango

Are there any resources for working on Project Tango at the OS level?  I've done a number of things to AOSP proper for Nexus devices, and I see the links to download the kernel source + external libraries on the SDK download page, but I was wondering if anyone has a working "repo manifest" like AOSP uses.  Working on a Project Tango hackathon in Nashville, TN this weekend and would love to poke around at the internals :-)

If this doesn't exist, I'll make a tutorial for it!

Comment: Hi Zach, The BSP on Tango is not open sourced.